# Send "Thank you" after bulk import contributions

Tags: contributions

I'd like to import a lot of contributions monthly. After import is done, I can create a custom search, to find all members, who's contributions are imported, and can send them a "Thank You"-letter, but my question is, if is it possible to send "Thank You" emails immediately, automatically after the import? (I've tried to create a rule in CiviRule, but I Can't find out, how to send "thank You" mail.)

CMS: Drupal 7, CRM: CiviCRM 5.60

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In CiviRules, you can add a `Send E-mail` Action with an email template that you've created at Administer - Communications - Message Templates. You can use a `Contribution is added` Trigger, but you'll need to figure out a condition that will only select your imported contributions. Maybe Financial Type, Campaign or Payment Method would work? Or perhaps you could use a custom Contribution Status and then change them all after?

Comment: OK, one thing is essential, for having `Send Email` action, you have to install  `Email API` extension. Than everting works fine...